# ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$

Tags: postgresql

I'm using [sql fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com)...PostgreSQL 9.3:

```
CREATE TABLE HotelStays
(roomNum INTEGER NOT NULL,
arrDate DATE NOT NULL,
depDate DATE NOT NULL,
guestName CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (roomNum, arrDate))
;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_customer() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    depatureDate DATE;\
BEGIN
    SELECT depDate INTO depatureDate FROM HotelStays WHERE OLD.roomNum = NEW.roomNum;
    IF (depatureDate <= NEW,arrDate)
      INSERT INTO HotelStays (roomNum, arrDate, depDate, guestName)
    VALUES (:NEW.roomNum, :NEW.arrDate, :NEW.depDate, :NEW.guestName);
    END IF;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
CREATE TRIGGER;

INSERT INTO HotelStays(roomNum, arrDate, depDate, guestName)
VALUES 
(123, to_date('20160202', 'YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160206','YYYYMMDD'), 'A');
```

Problem I am trying to solve: a new entry (for a new guest) could be put in for a room number, even before the existing guest has checked out.
I'm trying to solve this question using triggers. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it the slash at the line depatureDate DATE;\?

Comment: or is it the line LANGUAGE... try removing the LANGUAGE line

Answer (score 31):

As author mentioned, he used SQL Fiddle. I had the same problem with db-fiddle.com and resolved it by replacing `$$` or `$BODY$` with single quotes `'` (and doubling single quotes elsewhere in between.

For example, [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/63vo1RyCMorMsZLZjUE6UF/0)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_datem()
  RETURNS trigger AS
'
BEGIN
 NEW.dateM = DATE_TRUNC(''MONTH'', NEW.date);
 RETURN NEW;
END;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
Was facing same issue in Liquibase migration scripts.
Replacing "$$" with single quote did the work !!

Comment: I was running my original script with `$$` in IntelliJ and it was fine, but Liquibase migrations were failing. This solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in your code. First the backslash in `depatureDate DATE;\`. You are also missing a `THEN` for the `IF` clause and `new` does not need a `:` in front of it. You also have a `,` instead of a `.` in `NEW,arrDate`. And the final `END` is missing a `;`.

Not an error, but the language name is an identifier, do not put it in single quotes.

The line  `CREATE TRIGGER;` is also wrong. If you want to create trigger your function also needs to be declared as `returns trigger` and **has** to return the new row if it is a "before" trigger. If you intend to use an after trigger you still need to return something from that.

I am not sure what the condition `WHERE OLD.roomNum = NEW.roomNum;` is supposed to select. If you want to get the room number of the changed row, just use `new.depdate`. The `select .. into ...` will fail if that query returns more then one row. You probably meant to use `where roomnum = new.roomnum` or something similar.

So the function should be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_customer() 
  RETURNS trigger 
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    depatureDate DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT depDate 
       INTO depatureDate 
    FROM HotelStays 
    WHERE roomNum = NEW.roomNum;

    IF (depatureDate <= NEW.arrDate) THEN
      INSERT INTO HotelStays (roomNum, arrDate, depDate, guestName)
      VALUES (NEW.roomNum, nEW.arrDate, NEW.depDate, NEW.guestName);
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW; -- this is important for a trigger
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And the code to create the trigger would be something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_stays
  before update or insert on hotelstays
  execute procedure new_customer();
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$
DECLARE
    depatureDate DATE". Could you please help me out

Comment: @SunilkumarVuppala: works for me. Which SQL client are you using? Maybe that doesn't understand dollar quoting. What happens if you use "regular" single quotes for the function body? And what is your **exact** Postgres version? (output of `select version()`)

Comment: I'm using sql fiddle...PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: You need to change the script delimiter to something else then `;` in the dropdown below the left-hand input field. E.g. to a slash: `/`. Then replace the final `;` for each statement with the `/` on a single line: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2cee0