# Anonymous PostgreSQL PL/SQL in Informatica pre/post-sql

Tags: postgresql, plsql, informatica

I am trying to execute an anonymous PostgreSQL PL/SQL block in the pre or post SQL of a source qualifier in an Informatica mapping. PostgreSQL PL/SQL blocks require either $$ or $$ after the 'do' and the 'end' keywords.

A mapping with an anonymous PostgreSQL PL/SQL block in pre-sql like this:

```
do $$ 
begin
   raise notice '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Test Proc';
end $$;
```

Fails with this error:

```
Database driver error...
CMN_1022 [do $$
begin
   raise notice '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Test Proc'
FnName: Execute Direct -- [Informatica][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver][PostgreSQL]ERROR: VERROR; unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$
begin
   raise notice '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Test Proc'"(Position 4; File scan.l; Line 1236; Routine scanner_yyerror; ), SQLSTATE [37000]
]
```

I tried an alternate form of this, putting text between the $ characters, but get the same error. I think it is interpreting the '$' as an Informatica mapping parameter, which it is not. I have tried escaping the characters, single-quote, double-quote, etc, but can't get it to work. I would prefer not to do it as a stored procedure if I don't have to.

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be dollar-quoting, you can use normal single quotes. But then you need to escape any text literals in the body. There must be a way to escape dollar signs in the driver. If it isn't $$$$ you need perhaps \$\$ or \\$\\$ ?

Comment: There must be a ; after end

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. It works if I do it like this, single-quotes in place of the $$, and double single-quotes for anything in the block using single-quotes:


do '
begin
    raise notice ''>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Test Proc'';
end ';

Comment: There does not need to be a semi-colon after the 'end'. In fact, adding that will make it fail even outside of Informatica. The correct solution is to get rid of the '$$' and replace with single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Look like this is the solution...single-quotes in place of the $$, and double single-quotes for anything in the block using single-quotes:

```
do '
begin raise notice ''>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Test Proc''; 
end ';
```

Also referenced here [ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516386/error-unterminated-dollar-quoted-string-at-or-near-body)